# OnCollisionEnter2D() does not call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

OnCollisionEnter2D is not calling, what should I do?
Is this because of not adding layer to Edit>Unity Uroject>Phicycs2D? How can I do this? 
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Post your code also ...

Answer (score 0):

Try OnTriggerEnter2D() and check the is_trigger box on the collider. Otherwise, make sure that both objects are on the same layer.

Comment: void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        
        print(1);
        Debug.Log(1);
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy") && !canshoot && gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            enemy Enemy = col.gameObject.GetComponent<enemy>();
            Enemy.LifeDecrease(power);
            audioS.PlayOneShot(audioLife);
        }

    }
}

Comment: are you sure you have is_trigger checked?

Comment: also if you have 2 coliders on the same object then it may only sense one.

Comment: I tryed every way